# Ionic 2 Angular 2 ion-list random shuffle without ngFor

Tags: angular, random, ionic2, shuffle, ngfor

I have a list like this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>item A</ion-item>
    <ion-item>item B</ion-item>
    <ion-item>item C</ion-item>
<ion-list>
```

How to shuffle it randomly before rendering? Note, that we are not using ngFor.

Comment: is there a reason you are not using ngFor? If so, please add it. If you list the items just as shown they will always be rendered in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer very simply, you should just take a look at that **[shuffle technic](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/)**. This way you'll be able to randomly sort your array before rendering it. Create the following function in your component.

```
private buildArray(array) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let m = array.length, t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

      // Pick a remaining element…
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

      // And swap it with the current element.
      t = array[m];
      array[m] = array[i];
      array[i] = t;
    }

    this.myArray = array;
    resolve(true);
  });
}
```

Then, **in your constructor** you can just do something like :

```
this.buildArray(this.myArray);
```

Then to render it, you have multiple option, you can use *ngFor now because your array is randomly sort, but if for any other reason you prefer to make a rendering function, do the following :

```
<ion-list id="myArrayList"><ion-list>
```

Make your rendering function :

```
private renderArray(array, id){
  let item;
  let textItem;
  let i = -1;

  while(array[++i]) {
    item     = document.createElement("ion-item"); // Create item
    textItem = document.createTextNode(array[i].value); // Create item content

    item.appendChild(textItem);
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(item);
  }
}
```

finally modify your constructor the following way :

```
this.buildArray(this.myArray).then(() => {
  this.renderArray(this.myArray, "myArrayList");
});
```

I didn't try that code, so tell me if it works and if you need more help ^_^